# Paypal - Redirect with PHP?

Tags: php, html, paypal

What I'm trying to is redirect my buyers to a page: `http://url.com` when a transaction is successful, however, it only redirects them to a paypal page. I have tried to use the "Take customers to this URL when they finish checkout" option, but that doesn't help. I also tried adding:

`<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://url.com">`

but that doesn't work. I'm trying to avoid using the auto-return URL option, because I want to have multiple buttons that will return to unique URLs. Can anybody give me some pointers or examples on how to do this?

**I'm using a *Buy Now* button**

Here's my full code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://url.com">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="63ZZBGJ8ZMLAL">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: I need to see more of your code to understand what you're doing, are you interfacing to Paypal?  What does that code look like?

Comment: I suggest you read PayPal's technical support resources, they should explain everything in depth.

Comment: show us the whole code, this seems to be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PayPal allows you to send your own variables (what the user bought, his member number etc.) through their system, and when they return the user to your page (which you should, in my opinion, define through the setup they provide) they will forward these parameters along with their own and you can use them to either re-direct the user to whatever page you want (in this case the return URL will point to a script the user will never see), or to dynamically output different versions of the same page. Look at the PayPal documentation to see how to pass variables.

[PayPal's documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables) suggests that you use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="whatever you want to pass through">
```

and you can use:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://url.com?your_variable=whatever%20you%20want">
```

Please also take note, that the transaction details are not passed along to the return page. These are instead passed to notify_url, where you specify a page that collects and processes the transaction details. This page is never shown to the buyer. You must define a notify_url, if you want to automatically react to the transaction details, e.g. different kinds of membership, depending on amount of payment, or activation of membership upon completion of payment. If you don't specify a notify_url, all you can do is thank your user.